# SP 2010: List overview of logged on user access  (500 sites, 30.000 users)

Tags: development

We have a platform with 500 site collections and over 30000 users.
One of the requirements is to list an overview of the sites (on the central site collection:Home page) the logged in user has access to.

The question is if anyone has some ideas on how to implement this,
taking performance etc. into account? (Load time)

The info should more or less be available on the fly and not generated at the moment the user lands on the home page.

Any ideas or remarks are more than welcome!

Kind Regards,
Wim

Answer (score 1):

There is an in built component that probably does close to what you require, the My Site Membership.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-the-memberships-on-your-my-site-HA010168640.aspx

The inner workings of it basically is a timer job that looks up all the sites a user is in the "Members" site group and then caches the result for a web part to display.

If you need to build your own, i'd probably look at copying how the default one works.